# Listing Output?

Tags: c#

I have an app that recurses through a drive and outputs files that have "invalid" characters.  Now that I have to put a UI to it, i'm a bit confused.

Prior to this being a WinForm app, the code was (mind you, this STARTED as a Console App):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //recurse through files.  Let user press 'ok' to move onto next step        
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\bob.smith\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.Write(file + "\r\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        //End section


        //Regex -- find invalid chars
        string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
        string replacement = " ";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\bob.smith\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> filePath = new List<string>();

        //clean out file -- remove the path name so file name only shows

        foreach(string fileNames in fileDrive)
        {
        filePath.Add(fileNames);
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"S:\bob.smith\File_Renames.txt"))
        {
            //Sanitize and remove invalid chars  
            foreach (string Files2 in filePath)
            {
                try
                {
                    string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(Files2);
                    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(Files2);
                    string sanitizedFilename = regEx.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                    string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFilename);
                    sw.Write(sanitized + "\r\n");
                    System.IO.File.Move(Files2, sanitized);

                }
                //error logging
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"S:\bob.smith\Error_Log.txt");
                    sw2.Write("ERROR LOG");
                    sw2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ex + "\r\n");
                    sw2.Flush();
                    sw2.Close();

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now that i have to implement a UI, i was hoping to populate a ListView with file names that contain invalid characters.  I ONLY want to display those files that need to be renamed -- not all files like it's doing now.  How do i do this and have it list these files in the ListView?  Anybody have any syntax that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(string fileNames in fileDrive)
{
    if(regex.IsMatch(fileNames)) //check that it has invalid characters
    {
        filePath.Add(fileNames);
        yourListView.Items.Add(fileNames); //Add the string to your list view
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not able to add items to my listview.  For some reason intellisense is not letting me do so--any ideas on why?

Comment: When you move this code to the Winform App, you'll be running it in a form class. Intellisense won't recognize the listview unless you're inside the class that it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Not as it sits now.  You're sanitizing all the files whether they need it or not and not tracking what is done.  If you did a regexp to match the files that contained the characters and moved only those files into the list that needs to be re-written:

```
foreach(string fileNames in fileDrive) 
{ 
    if(matchesregexp(filenames))
        filePath.Add(fileNames); 
}
```

Then fix the names for those files and output that list to your ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to the existing code:

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"S:\bob.smith\File_Renames.txt")) 
    { 
        //Sanitize and remove invalid chars   
        foreach (string Files2 in filePath) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                if (regex.Match(Files2).Success) 
                {
                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.Content = Files2;
                    listview.Items.Add(l);
                }
                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(Files2); 
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(Files2); 
                string sanitizedFilename = regEx.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement); 
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFilename); 
                sw.Write(sanitized + "\r\n"); 
                System.IO.File.Move(Files2, sanitized); 

            } 
            //error logging 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"S:\bob.smith\Error_Log.txt"); 
                sw2.Write("ERROR LOG"); 
                sw2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ex + "\r\n"); 
                sw2.Flush(); 
                sw2.Close(); 

            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: i can't add this code!  it won't recognize my listview on my winform.  I tried adding this after List<string>filePath = new List<string>();

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this piece of code?

```
        ListView blah = new ListView();
        this.Controls.Add(blah);
        blah.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        blah.Items.Add("hello");
```

If so, you should be able to use the code above.